# Sharepoint - Custom ItemStyle in a new file

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2007

how can I customize the presentation of a Content Query Web Part by modyfing the xsl it uses **without** touching ItemStyle.xsl but using a brand new .xsl file?

I'm using MOSS 2007.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are lots of Articles on Customising the CQWP,

Healther Soloman's being one of my faves 
[here](http://www.heathersolomon.com/blog/articles/CustomItemStyle.aspx)

But [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mcsnoiwb/archive/2009/08/31/aggregating-content-with-the-content-query-web-part-cqwp.aspx)
is a succint article doing exactly what you describe
using your own xsl by changing the Settings in the DWP (export/edit/import)

You could get really fancy and create your own version of the CQWP by inheriting from  ContentByQueryWebPart and setting all the attributes you want in that code and including the files in you new feature to house said webpart and new files.